# How do I give players slowness if they have low health?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a minigame in which I'm adding a slowness factor when your health gets low.

I'm trying to give *Slowness I* to anyone with less than 7 hearts and *Slowness II* to people with less than 4 hearts. The effect would disappear if your health was regenerated.

Actually, I don't know where to even start. I made an objective scoreboard with health of every player using `/scoreboard objectives add HealthBar health HealthBar`, so what next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish this, you need to use the `/effect` command and an `@a` selector that selects all the players with your given criteria.

Having a scoreboard already set up is a good start. You can select all players with a maximum score in objective `name` with `@a[score_name=x]`. So, in this case, you would use `@a[score_HealthBar=14]` (since health is tracked in half-heart increments).

The `effect` command syntax is `/effect give <player> <effect> [seconds] [amplifier] [hideParticles]`. `<player>` will become your target selector from above. `<effect>` is a status effect ID (in this case, `minecraft:slowness`). `[seconds]` doesn't matter too much if you're constantly reapplying this, so I would just set it to 10, just to make sure the effect doesn't clear before the command runs again. `[amplifier]` is a little weird; it corresponds to how strong the effect should be, above 1. This means that to get level 2, you'd enter a 1 here.

You can also clear effects with `/effect clear <player> [effect]`, and invert your selector with `score_name_min`, to achieve the opposite effect for players with at least 7.5 hearts.

All of these elements come together to give you the following commands:

```
/effect give @a[score_HealthBar=14] minecraft:slowness 10 1
/effect clear @a[score_HealthBar_min=15] minecraft:slowness
```

Plug these into a pair of repeating command blocks, and you should be good to go.

Comment: If you're in a version prior to 1.13, the effect syntax is slightly different; get rid of the `give` and `clear` parts, and to clear, just use a time of 0.

Comment: Also, this needs to use the new syntax for scoreboards in 1.13: `/@a[scores={HealthBar=..14}`]